# A utility class(a 3rd jar file ) for Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a utility class or a 3rd jar file that can make us use regular expressions easily.

I would expect it would provides the following methods:

```
boolean matchString(int length);

boolean matchInt(int min,int max);
......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Java has supported regular expressions through the standard package `java.util.regex` since JDK 1.4, and it is what you should really be using.

If you're looking for the actual .jar for that package, check out `rt.jar`.

As for third-party .jar files, you might try:

- http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/
- http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregex/